# Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=120 uv=1

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, database, next.js13

I have a nextjs application, in the database I am using [Level](https://github.com/Level/level)
I get this error after rendering any route, and I guess the issue from Level

```
 ⨯ node_modules/node-gyp-build/node-gyp-build.js (60:0) @ load.resolve.load.path
 ⨯ Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=120 uv=1 libc=glibc node=21.6.2 webpack=true
    loaded from: /home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/vendor-chunks

    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/lib/db.js:2:19)
    at (ssr)/./src/lib/db.js (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/app/page.js:316:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/lib/utils.ts:13:61)
    at (ssr)/./src/lib/utils.ts (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/app/page.js:338:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/components/ui/pagination.tsx:18:72)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/ui/pagination.tsx (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/app/page.js:305:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/components/list.tsx:12:87)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/list.tsx (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/app/page.js:272:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
null
 ⨯ node_modules/node-gyp-build/node-gyp-build.js (60:0) @ load.resolve.load.path
 ⨯ Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=120 uv=1 libc=glibc node=21.6.2 webpack=true
    loaded from: /home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/vendor-chunks

    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/lib/db.js:2:19)
    at (ssr)/./src/lib/db.js (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/app/page.js:316:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/lib/utils.ts:13:61)
    at (ssr)/./src/lib/utils.ts (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/app/page.js:338:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/components/ui/pagination.tsx:18:72)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/ui/pagination.tsx (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/app/page.js:305:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/components/list.tsx:12:87)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/list.tsx (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/app/page.js:272:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/oussama/Desktop/imagee/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
null
```

Here is how I set up the Level

/src/lib/db.js

```
const { Level } = require("level");

// Create a database
const dbPath = "./database";
const db = new Level(dbPath, { valueEncoding: "json" });

module.exports = db;
```

I tried install lower version of nodejs